# Gtk3 - unresolved inclusion

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gtk, eclipse-cdt

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4, and Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0) and I try to create a little C application with the help of Glade for the user interface.

Adding the following header files in C results in "unresolved inclusion" error:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
```

I have searched and tried in many ways to fix this, but unfortunately I didn't manage (I am new to linux/eclipse). The most easy solution seems to be a package called "Pkg-config" that knows itself how to add the gtk package, but unfortunately, this version of Eclipse does not support it.

The compiler sends the following error:

```
10:22:19 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MyTestProject ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/MyTestProject.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/MyTestProject.d" -MT"src/MyTestProject.o" -o "src/MyTestProject.o" "../src/MyTestProject.c"
../src/MyTestProject.c:17:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/MyTestProject.o' failed
make: *** [src/MyTestProject.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

10:22:19 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 466ms)
```

Any ideas how I can solve this? I mention that libgtk-3-dev is installed on my system and it appears inside the "includes" folder.

Comment: Do you also have `libgtk-3-dev` installed on your machine?

Comment: You can also run `pkg-config` on command line and see the flags you might need to add to your Eclipse project.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, I do

Comment: @Gerhardh Can you please show me or send me a reference link on how I can do that? (I am new to it)

Comment: For compiler flags use `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` and for libraries use`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: @Gerhardh I included the error from the compiler in the original message now. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210785/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-andrei-rosu).